# Как высчитать индекс числа из string без учета запятых?

Tags: python

```py
a = '|'.join( '%s,%s,%s' % (i - 2, i - 1, i) for i in range(3, 101))
    
print(a)
    
string = (a)
b = input()

print(string.find(b)+1))
```

Вывод происходит таким образом:

```
1,2,3|2,3,4|3,4,5|4,5,6|5,6,7|6,7,8|7,8,9|8,9,10|9,10,11|10,11,12|11,12,13|12,13,14|13,14,15|14,15,16|15,16,17|16,17,18|17,18,19|18,19,20
```

Нужно чтобы он считал индекс числа без учета каких либо знаков, только числа

Если все знаки убрать, например число 12, он будет определять как первый индекс

Comment: ничего не понятно.

Comment: если ты решаешь какую-то задачу на порядковый номер числа в такой последовательности, то задача решается аналитически, простой формулой, без всяких строк и поисков индекса

Comment: @Эникейщик, это явно всё [про то же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1510874/178576), про последовательность [A001703](https://oeis.org/A001703)

Comment: @Эникейщик мне нужно из списка определить индекс числа, именно индекс

Comment: какой индекс должен быть у 12 в этом примере?

Comment: Вопрос по сути никак не касается tkinter, убрал метку, подредактировал код.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да я уже вижу что тут кто-то пытается коллективным разумом решить свою учебную/олимпиадную задачку :)

Comment: @insolor у 12 не должен быть индекс 1, должен быть 30, но он считается вместе с запятыми.

Comment: Ок, значит исходно собирайте числа в список а не в строку, потом просто через `a.index(b)` находите нужный индекс.

Comment: ну я и говорю - порядковый номер в последовательности. Считается формулой за одно действие, без всяких строк